# run shell command in compute engine from java app engine

Tags: shell, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to run a shell command in a compute engine instance from java app engine

I couldn't find a clean and good solution to do that so, at the moment what I'm doing is to update our database from our app engine, to run an app into the compute engine instance that check the database and in case there are some changes, run the shell command in the compute engine instance directly from the app that is checking the db and running inside the compute engine instance

I think that is not the best solution but it's the only one that I could find.
The best solution should be just send the command to run from our app engine to the compute engine instance, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do that

Any tip?
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to instance processes on a GCE instance from GAE would be to use either [pull queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/rest/) or [sub/pub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries)

There is no way to directly start a shell command on GCE for GAE instances since that would be different systems/servers.